# Search on Multiple Terms in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

I want to search a Thunderbird (v31.2, Windows) collection of 7,000 emails.  Each email mentions (in the body) an individual product by its numeric SKU.  I want to find the emails that mention any from a list of 112 SKUs I am researching.

The Filter or QuickFilter only handle one at a time, no way to "OR" them.  Any multiple terms are ANDed, which of course returns nothing since no email references more than one SKU.

Any ideas, other than pasting in one at a time, 112 times?

Comment: Hopefully you will be able to do a search with multiple terms using quotations. The option is detailed in the following link: "Searching for multiple terms": https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/global-search#w_searching-for-multiple-terms

Comment: My understanding, and light testing, indicate that those are evaluated with AND, not OR